# вставить тег в option для изменения класса другого элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

на [сайте](http://veles-61.ru/shop/linens/kpb-poplin-detail)

есть выпадающий список с размерами постельного , мне нужно как то подцепится к  option что бы при нажатие на него менялся класс у другого блока

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так?

```js
$('.vm-chzn-select').bind('change', function(){
  let i = $(this).val(); // Получаем выбранный
  i = $(this).find('option[value="'+i+'"]').index(); // Получаем позицию выбранного option
  let sClass; // Создаём переменную под класс
  // Если выбран n option, то класс "рабочего" элемента..
  if(i==0) sClass = '.item1';
  if(i==1) sClass = '.item2';
  if(i==2) sClass = '.item3';
  if(i==3) sClass = '.item4';
  if(i==4) sClass = '.item5';
  if(i==5) sClass = '.item6';
  /* Если все .item содержат вконце число равное выбранному option, то можно упростить условие выше.
  sClass = '.item'+i; // отсчёт с 0
  sClass = '.item'+(i+1); // отсчёт с 1
  */
  // Удаляем класс active со всех .block
  $('.block.active').removeClass('active');
  // Ну и добавляем к .block и .item'n ↑ класс .active
  $('.block'+sClass).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.block {display: inline-block; float: left; width: 50px; height: 50px; line-height: 50px; text-align: center; background: green; margin-right: 5px;}
.block.item3,
.block.item6 {line-height: 15px; padding: 10px 0; box-sizing: border-box;}
.block.active {background: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="customProductData[359][56]" class="vm-chzn-select">
 <option value="3398">1,5 спальный</option>
 <option value="3399">2 спальный</option>
 <option value="3400">2 спальный с ЕВРО простыней</option>
 <option value="3401">Евро</option>
 <option value="3402">Семейный</option>
 <option value="3403">Семейный 4</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<div class="item1 block">1,5</div>
<div class="item2 block">2</div>
<div class="item3 block">2 (euro)</div>
<div class="item4 block">euro</div>
<div class="item5 block">family</div>
<div class="item6 block">family 4</div>
```

Думаю комментарии к коду ясны, если нет, то не стесняйтесь, спрашивайте в комментах.

---

Почитав комментария к другому ответу.

```js
$('.vm-chzn-select').bind('change', function(){
  let i = $(this).val(); // Получаем выбранный
  i = $(this).find('option[value="'+i+'"]').index(); // Получаем позицию выбранного option
  
  // Удаляем класс active с активного .kit
  $('.kits .kit.active').removeClass('active');
  // Ну и добавляем к .kit с индексом выбранного option класс .active
  $('.kits .kit').eq(i).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.kit.active {color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="customProductData[359][56]" class="vm-chzn-select">
 <option value="3398">1,5 спальный</option>
 <option value="3399">2 спальный</option>
 <option value="3400">2 спальный с ЕВРО простыней</option>
 <option value="3401">Евро</option>
 <option value="3402">Семейный</option>
 <option value="3403">Семейный 4</option>
</select>

<div class="kits">
  <div class="kit">В комплект "1,5 спальный" входит:</div>
  <div class="kit">В комплект "2 спальный" входит:</div>
  <div class="kit">В комплект "2 спальный с ЕВРО простыней" входит:</div>
  <div class="kit">В комплект "Евро" входит:</div>
  <div class="kit">В комплект "Семейный" входит:</div>
  <div class="kit">В комплект "Семейный 4" входит:</div>
</div>
```

В качестве "комплектаций" можете использовать "блоки "спойлеры"", или "[вкладки (табы)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/938955/221218)"

Comment: спасибо больше . я поставил код на сайт но не работает почему то

Comment: @ЭлвинАлиев, мой код написан как пример, он не настроен под ваш сайт и желания - естественно, скопировав его как есть, он и не заработает.

Comment: на другом сайте работает а тут нет, конфликт что ли

Comment: @ЭлвинАлиев, конфликты и их много - [скриншот](https://i.imgur.com/epKtLWC.png), но они все с другими скриптами, из-за чего мой не работает.

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery('.vm-chzn-select').on('change', function() {
      console.log('any actions')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: я прописал на сайте ,не чего не происходит

Comment: Что собственно должно происходить, можно подробнее? У какого блока доллжен менять класс, и на какой класс?

Comment: https://matras-strong.ru/catalog/postelnoe-bele/komplekt-postelnogo-belya-margarita/ нужно по концу что бы как тут было если выбрать из списка нужный размер и нажать Что входит в комплект? то снизу открывается описание для выбранного размера

Comment: как тут, что именно? свиду, или о чем ричеь идет?не ясно ничего